# Looping through records to execute a stored procedure and store the result

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure `sp_OrderPrice_Calc` that takes an `OrderNumber` and returns a scalar valued `Order Price`. I'm trying loop the above stored procedure for a list of order numbers **without** using a cursor.

I have the following logic in place, but the output is not as expected. I would really appreciate any suggestions/changes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @orderInfo AS TABLE 
                      (
                          ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), 
                          CompanyName VARCHAR(40), 
                          OrderNumber VARCHAR(40), 
                          DeliveryType VARCHAR(40), 
                          OrderPrice DECIMAL(6,1)
                      )

INSERT INTO @orderInfo (CompanyName, OrderNumber, DeliveryType)
    SELECT CompanyName, OrderNumber, DeliveryType
    FROM OrderData

DECLARE @ID INT = 1, @OrderNumber VARCHAR(40), @OrderPrice DECIMAL(6,1)

WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT @OrderNumber = OrderNumber
    FROM @orderInfo 
    WHERE ID = @ID
   
    INSERT INTO @orderInfo (OrderPrice)
       EXEC sp_OrderPrice_Calc @Order_Number = @OrderNumber, @Order_Price  = @OrderPrice
   
    SELECT @ID = MIN(ID) 
    FROM @OrderInfo 
    WHERE ID > @ID; 
END

SELECT * FROM @OrderInfo
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Note:** I have created the stored procedure that it should take `@Order_Number` as Input and `@order_Price` as Output, which I used in the above logic

E.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[spCDS_TP_TW_limit] 
     @Order_Number VARCHAR(50) = '',
     @order_Price decimal(6,1) OUTPUT
AS
```

The above logic is returning "Null" for Each Order_Number record in the output

```
CompanyName  OrderNumber  DeliveryType  OrderPrice
--------------------------------------------------
  ABBCCC      123456        Standard     NULL
  DDDDEE      147852        Standard     NULL
  EEEFFF      159635        Priority     NULL
  FFFFGG      163589        Ground       NULL
```

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few misunderstandings here.

First, you will need to understand that when you use the form `insert into table (columns...) exec procedure`, the thing that gets inserted is the *result set* of the stored procedure. In other words, whatever comes out of a select statement inside the procedure. If your stored procedure has no result set, there is nothing to insert. Note that *output* parameters are *not* the same as a result set. Observe what happens if you run the following batches:

```sql
create table t(result varchar(30))
go

create  procedure p (@result varchar(30) = null output) as 
begin 
    set @result = 'this is the output parameter';
    select 'this is the result set'; 
end
go

declare @param varchar(30);
insert t (result) exec p @param output;
select * from t; 
select @param;
```

At the end of the execution of this script, the table `t` will have a single row with the value '"this is the result set". The value of the `@param` variable will be "this is the output parameter".

OK, now let's look at what's going on in your procedure.

You use the `insert ... exec` pattern, so the result set from the stored procedure will be *inserted* as new rows into your `@orderInfo` table.

But from what you have written, it seems like you intend the price to be provided as an `output` parameter value to be consumed by your `@orderPrice` variable. It won't actually do this, because you haven't used it as an output parameter. You left off the `output` keyword.

I expect your stored procedure has no result set at all. Which means nothing gets inserted into the table.

Even if the stored procedure *did* return a result set, you are doing an `insert`. An `insert` will create new rows, it won't update the value of the `OrderPrice` column for an existing row.

What you probably intend to be doing is this:

```
While @ID IS NOT NULL
 BEGIN
   Select @OrderNumber = OrderNumber;
   From @orderInfo Where ID = @ID;
      
   Exec sp_OrderPrice_Calc 
      @Order_Number = @OrderNumber, 
      @Order_Price  = @OrderPrice output; -- output keyword is required both here and in the procedure definition

   update @orderInfo set OrderPrice = @orderPrice where ID = @ID; -- update, not insert.

   Select @ID = MIN(ID) From @OrderInfo where ID > @ID;
 END
```

There might be an even better solution to use here. If your stored procedure can be rewritten as a [user defined function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-user-defined-functions-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15), you wouldn't need a loop at all:

```
select CompanyName, OrderNumber, DeliveryType, OrderPrice = myOrderPriceFunction(...)
From OrderData;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I do have "user defined function" in my consideration but the proc was already written as Stored Proc and I'm trying to use it instead of modifying it to a function

Comment: @SudhaVuppala If you do go with a user defined function, you could look into making it an inline tabled value function which returns a single column and single row, instead of a scalar function returning a single scalar. You then `cross apply` the table valued function. This is typically *much* faster than a scalar function when used inside a select statement. There's a good article on this technique [here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-make-scalar-udfs-run-faster-sql-spackle)

Comment: @SudhaVuppala Also, let's say you want to keep the stored procedure version for use elsewhere. What you could do is create the function version, and then just have the stored procedure call the function. So the stored procedure becomes a "wrapper" around the function implementation. That way you get both the stored proc and the function version, but you only have to write the logic once.

Comment: I like the Wrapping idea of being used the existing Stored proc inside a function. Once again, thank you so much for your response and Ideas